# Hello.js: authenticate in same window

Tags: hello.js

When I call the `hello.login` it opens a new window on the browser. Is there a way to replace the current window and on the call back refresh the window to the app window. I would have liked a seamless look and feel in the Single Page App that I am building.

Thanks,

- Raj

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out. It can be set in one of the parameters of the login as below:

`hello.login({display:'page'})`

- Raj